# Mysql service stuck sometime not able to login to mysql after reboot the server

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-select-db, mysql-error-2002

I am using a mysql server but sometimes i face a problem that not able to login to mysql server  just after reboot the server Its not happen every time but  there is 2-3 case in 20 cases that mysql not able to login

Got a error 2002

is this okey or there is an issue we can fix.
please let me know
Thanks in advance.

when i found this issue my MYSQL service was running but i was not able to login to mysql when i restarted the mysqld service then i was able to login MYSQL.